# How to load data into Core Data?

Tags: iphone, core-data, persistent-storage

thanks for you help.

I'm attempting to add core data to my project and I'm stuck at where and how to add the actual data into the persistent store (I'm assuming this is the place for the raw data).

I will have 1000 < objects so I don't want to use a plist approach. From my searches, there seems to be xml and csv approaches.  Is there a way I can use SQL for input?

The data will not be changed by the user and the data file will be typed in by hand, so I won't need to update these files during runtime, and at this point I am not limited in any type of file - the lightest on syntax is preferred.

Thanks again for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could load your data from an xml/csv/json file and create the DB on the first lunch of your application (if the DB is not there, then read the data and create it).
A better/faster approach might be to ship your sqllite DB within your application. You can parse the file in any format you want on the simulator, create a DB with all your entities, then take it from the ApplicationData and just add it to your app as a resource.

Comment: Thanks.  I don't already have any data in place, but I'm very familiar with SQL. I thought it might be best to create a database and ship it in as you suggest, but @vicvicvic suggests otherwise. At this point I'm not tied to any data format, so perhaps I'll look at the json.

Comment: Please see my comment on @vicvicvic answer.

Answer (score 1):

Although I'm sure there are lighter file types that could be used, I would include a JSON file into the app bundle from which you import the initial dataset.

**Update**: some folks are recommending XML. NSXMLParser is almost as fast as JSONKit (but much faster than most other parsers), but the XML syntax is heavier than JSON. So an XML bundled file that holds the initial dataset would weight more than if it was in JSON.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  I'll look into what making a JSON file involves. Speaking of importing the initial dataset, is that within this code: NSURL *storeUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory]stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"<xcdatamodel_name>.sqlite"]]; ?

Comment: Do you have a recommendation on parsers? There's a short list offered at the bottom of this page: http://www.json.org/

Comment: [JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit) is known to be the fastest, but [TouchJSON](https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchJSON) is probably the most widespread. Both include documentation that will show you how to parse your json file into NSObjects that you can then save to CoreData.

Answer (score 0):

Considering Apple considers the format of its persistent stores implementation details, shipping a prefabricated SQLite database is not a very good idea. I.e. the names of fields and tables **may** change between iOS versions/phones/whatever hidden variable you can think of. You should, in general, not concern yourself with how this serialization of your data is formatted.

There's a brief article about importing data on Apple's developer site: [Efficiently Importing Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdImporting.html)

You should ship initial data in whatever format you're comfortable with (XML allows you to do incremental parsing efficiently, which reduces memory footprint) and write an import routine to run if you need to import data.

**Edit:** With EliBud's comment in mind, I still consider the approach a bit "iffy"... The format of the SQLite database used by Core Data is not something you'd want to generate by yourself (it's weird, simply put, and still not something you should really *rely on*).

So you'd want to use a mock app running on the Simulator and use Core Data to create the database (as per EliBud's answer). But you'd still have to import the data into **that** mock-app! And while it might make sense to do this once on a "real" computer instead of a lot of times on a mobile device (i.e. copying a file is easy, importing data is hard), you're essentially using the Simulator as an administration tool.

But hey, if it works...

Comment: I don't plan on getting any data from online sources, and I have hundreds of entries to type out, do you still suggest that XML be the best choice? From examples I've seen of XML, the data is surrounded by a lot of syntax, which seems like unnecessary extra work - unless I'm going to need the parsing?

Comment: Looking at that same document, in the last section (FAQ), it states: "There are several ways to create the data.
You can create a separate persistent store that contains the default data and include the store as an application resource. When you want to use it, you must either copy the whole store to a suitable location, or copy the objects from the defaults store to an existing store." From that I read that it is OK to ship the DB as a resource, am I missing something?

Comment: @EliBud: Huh, you're quite right... I'll admit I had not read that section and am quite surprised. So, I guess... it's ok?

Comment: @Ernest: Pros: XML can be very efficiently parsed in iOS, and it's a highly standardized format. See: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/XMLParsing/XMLParsing.html I appreciate it being stream-based and built-in (adding external libraries on iOS can be a *bit of a pain*). But yes, it's very verbose. Are you going to create your initial data manually?

Comment: Yes, I have to type it in.  It won't be stripped from anywhere.  I looked into the JSON file - as I never heard of it before - and it seems quite attractive, especially since my background is in Java.  The only drawback I can see is if I do want the versatility to draw from online content. So at this point, I've decided to try the JSON file, which I've created a tiny one to test.  My problem is how to get this file into CoreData? I've got all the template methods in the delegate, do I include my file name in this method? - (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator, as NSURL*

Comment: You'll have to parse it (using a library), and insert the results using "regular" Core Data methods (insert into managed object context and save it, etc). You can't just use the JSON file as a persistent store, unfortunately.

Comment: Do I just parse as I need it or parse the whole thing once?

Comment: Well, you'll only want to insert initial data once (i.e. when the user installs the app), right? So that's the one time you'll need to parse it.